# How do I use SDL_LockTexture() to update dirty rectangles?

Tags: c, graphics, sdl, sdl-2

I'm migrating an application from SDL 1.2 to 2.0, and it keeps an array of dirty rectangles to determine which parts of its SDL_Surface to draw to the screen. I'm trying to find the best way to integrate this with SDL 2's SDL_Texture.

Here's how the SDL 1.2 driver is working: https://gist.github.com/nikolas/1bb8c675209d2296a23cc1a395a32a0d

And here's how I'm getting changes from the surface to the texture in SDL 2:

```
void *pixels;
int pitch;

SDL_LockTexture(_sdl_texture, NULL, &pixels, &pitch);
memcpy(
    pixels, _sdl_surface->pixels,
    pitch * _sdl_surface->h);
SDL_UnlockTexture(_sdl_texture);

for (int i = 0; i < num_dirty_rects; i++) {
    SDL_RenderCopy(
        _sdl_renderer, _sdl_texture, &_dirty_rects[i], &_dirty_rects[i]);
}

SDL_RenderPresent(_sdl_renderer);
```

I'm just updating the entire surface, but then taking advantage of the dirty rectangles in the RenderCopy(). Is there a better way to do things here, only updating the dirty rectangles? Will I run into problems calling SDL_LockTexture and UnlockTexture up to a hundred times every frame, or is that how they're meant to be used?

SDL_LockTexture accepts an SDL_Rect param which I could use here, but then it's unclear to me how to get the appropriate rect from `_sdl_surface->pixels`. How would I copy out just a small rect from this pixel data of the entire screen?

Comment: There are many factors that prevents us from making an estimate here; the only correct way is to measure. Mostly it depends on number of locks and percentage of changed data compared to entire texture. What bugs me in presented code is a rendering though - RenderPresent invalidates your image, you can't really render only changed regions and expect image to stay stable. If you already have a full texture, wouldn't it be both simplier and faster (not to mention 'correct') to just display it with single big RenderCopy?

Comment: Yeah, maybe one big RenderCopy is better. I will try putting LockTexture in the loop and updating things with one big RenderCopy. My question about SDL_LockTexture() remains, though: I'm having trouble finding an example of using `SDL_LockTexture()` to update a small rectangle out of an SDL_Surface. What I'm really trying to do here is some optimization: I'm seeing my SDL 2 driver is spending more time than SDL 1.2 rendering video output: (something like 1ms/t vs 0.02ms/t when the cursor is moved around rapidly). I've updated my question to show how the SDL 1.2 driver is blitting this surface.

Comment: The basic idea is to lock a region and perform a memcpy for each row, shifting by `pitch` each time (don't expecti pitch to match locked region size - it is likely to cover entire texture, not just locked rectangle). All of that implies your surface and texture pixel formats match, as you have in the question. Or use `SDL_ConvertPixels` and give it a pointer to locked rectangle and a pointer to first modified pixel in your surface.